# Android Dialog with List that uses custom list adapter randomly losing information when scrolled

Tags: android, eclipse, dialog, scroll, listadapter

I create a dialog and populate it with a listview that uses a custom list adapter.  It works fine, but I've noticed that when the list is long enough to scroll, doing so back and forth will cause some of my list items to randomly lose some of their data.  I've noticed it is always the same list items too.  For instance, each list item will have a title, image, and date on it.  The dates seem to vanish on some when I scroll.  They are always there when I start the dialog, and they always vanish once I scroll.

The weird thing is that my list row consists of a few TextViews in 2 rows and its only the bottom row TextViews that dissapear...Any ideas?

Code for my dialog

```
 itemSendPickerDialog = new Dialog(this);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   builder.setTitle("Select Item to Send");
    ListView lv = new ListView(this);
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchItemsByDate(id);
    c.moveToFirst();

    int i = R.layout.send_item_menu_row;
    MyListAdapter ia = new MyListAdapter(this, mainListBackground, c, true);
    lv.setAdapter(ia);

    builder.setView(lv);
    itemSendPickerDialog = builder.create();
    itemSendPickerDialog.show();
```

And my custom list adapter class:

```
class MyListAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {
    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int i, Cursor cursor, boolean...sending) {
        super(context, i, cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

        title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TripsDbAdapter.KEY_ITEM_TITLE)));

        Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        width = width - 150;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = title.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        title.setLayoutParams(params);

        String cat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TripsDbAdapter.KEY_ITEM_CATEGORY));
        if (cat.equalsIgnoreCase("trip notes")) {
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.item_datetime_holder);
            ll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_date);
        date.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TripsDbAdapter.KEY_DEP_DATE)));

        TextView time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_time);
        time.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TripsDbAdapter.KEY_DEP_TIME)));

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_icon);
        if (iv != null) {
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(TripsDbAdapter.KEY_ITEM_TYPE);

            String type = cursor.getString(index);
            if (type != null) {

            } else {
                type = "notes";
            }

            iv.setImageResource(getTypeResource(type));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please award the bounty points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that the code that is doing this is in my custom list adapter class

```
String cat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TripsDbAdapter.KEY_ITEM_CATEGORY));
        if (cat.equalsIgnoreCase("trip notes")) {   
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.item_datetime_holder);
            ll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

I hide some of the layout items depending on what the category is, and for some reason when putting a list view in an AlertDialog builder it appears to mix up the items.  I don't know exactly how I am going to fix it, but for now if I just remove the invisibility functionality, my data won't go away.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this problem too...
The problem you are facing is due to the recycling of views by the LIstView when you scroll up/down. In your case, the ListView is giving you those recycled views , whose properties you have changed by making them invisible. Some possible solutions could be:

1) When cat.equalsIgnoreCase("trip notes"))  is becoming true, you are making some views invisible. This invisible view is then recycled and given back. The recycled view is *still invisible* (when it is given back to you), so what you can do is make this invisible view *visible* in the beginning of your ListAdapter  every time . 
You can put this code at the beginning of bindView method where you make the layout visible first and then proceed with rest of the logic.( In short, the dates from your display are not vanishing but are just invisible).

2) Override `getViewTypeCount()` in you adapter . From your codesnippet, it looks like you have two types of rows( one in which R.id.item_datetime_holder is invisible and other in which it is visible) , so return 2 from this method( please do some trial and error ) . This should take care of the problem.

```
public int getViewTypeCount() {

        return 2;
    }
```

You will find an excellent explanation at this link http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/

3) You can inflate completely different layouts depending on your if condition. But the effeciency would be a little less.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, when scrolling a list, only the items after the window height decided to get their data repeating from index 0 - so if the last visible item was 8, the next would be 0 again.

So you could try to check if the index of the view is correct, maybe this method of ListView would help

```
lv.getPositionForView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use two different layouts, depending on the "type" of list item.  It looks like you are switching the "type" based on the cat string containing "trip notes".  If it contains it, then you would have a layout that is the same as you have now, but without the item_datetime_holder view.  If it doesn't contain it, then you would use the same layout as you're using now (send_item_menu_row).

Here is a good tutorial on how to use multiple layouts in a ListView: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

By the way, I think that the reason why some of your rows are not drawing correctly is due to view reuse by the ListView.  Utilizing the multiple layouts like I've mentioned above should fix the problem since you won't be changing the visibility of views, but just utilizing two different views to render, depending on what type of list item you're rendering.